# Installed Microsoft ReportViewer but can't add it to Toolbox

Tags: c#, report-viewer2010, reportviewer2008

I'm trying to use Microsoft **ReportViewer** in an application I'm building with C# in **Visual Studio 2010 Express**. ReportViewer isn't distributed by default with VSE 2010, so I wen to the Microsoft website and downloaded both **ReportViewer 2010** and **ReportViewer 2008** redistributable packages, however when I right-click on the toolbox to add them, they're nowhere to be found.

Any suggestion on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following link that indicates ReportViewer is not supported by VS2010 Express.

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/716777/unable-to-add-reportviewer-2008-2010-neither-to-visual-c-2010-express